# Using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener with .NET v 1.0

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a application in .net 1.0 which logs using `System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener` below is my `Service.exe.config`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
       <runtime>
          <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="1" />
       </runtime>
       <system.diagnostics>
          <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
             <listeners>
                <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="Service.log" />
             </listeners>
          </trace>
       </system.diagnostics>
    </configuration>
```

This configuration is creating huge log file and not rolling the file, after some research I found the below configuration which is using `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener` to rollover the log file daily

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="1"/>
    </runtime>
 <system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4"/>
    <sources>
    <source name="log" switchValue="All">
      <listeners>
        <add name="file" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, 
                         Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=7.0.0.0, 
                         Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
             BaseFileName="Service_daily.txt"
             DiskSpaceExhaustedBehavior="ThrowException"
             Location="ExecutableDirectory"
             MaxFileSize="81920000"
             LogFileCreationSchedule="Daily"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

After changing the config to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener` application starts fine but its not creating any log file with `Service_daily.txt` 
Can someone help me to create rolling log file using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener with .NET v 1.0

Comment: you know that .net 1.0 support ended nearly 10 years ago? you should try to migrate to a newer version.

Comment: @Fredou we are getting rid of our legacy products and migrating to newer version, meanwhile we want to fix this logging issue its generating huge log files and bringing the service down frequently